# Using #if DEBUG with Main arguments

Tags: c#

I have written this code in my console application:

```
#if DEBUG
            args = new[] {"4478676e34432432434"};
#endif

            if (args == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter IP for single testing for now.");
            }
```

When the tester person wants to test my app and forgets to enter the argument to run the app with I still want him to see that message. But now it does not do that. Does it mean should I put the **build** also on "`Release"`?  Does this `"DEBUG"` mean if we are in `VS IDE` or does it mean if we are in Debug/Release build?

Comment: I definitely recommend giving testers your Release build. Nothing worse than having something pass testing, only to fail in production because it's not what was actually tested.

Comment: If this is in main then `args == null` should always be false

Comment: @Tyler yeah I had to add a args.Count() to it too

Answer (score 5):

You can give them a release build, instead.  This is probably best, for reasons that @JoeEnos pointed out in his comment on your question.

Either way, it might be better to specify the command line arguments in the project properties, instead of in a conditional `#if DEBUG`. However, Visual Studio adds them to the local project properties, so it won't be checked in with the project, meaning that other developers won't have the command line arguments you used. In my experience, I've found this to be a good thing.

For information in adding command-line arguments for debugging, look at this [MSDN entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/1ktzfy9w(v=vs.100).aspx)

> To specify command-line arguments for debugging
>
> With a project selected in Solution Explorer, on the Project menu, click Properties.
>
> Click the Debug tab.
>
> In the Command line arguments field, enter the command-line arguments you wish to use.

Answer (score 3):

> Does this "DEBUG" mean if we are in VS IDE or does it mean if we are
>   in Debug/Release build?

It means the application has been built with the Debug configuration. By default the `DEBUG` symbol is defined only for this configuration (although you can change this in the project's build settings).

If you want the tester to see the message then provide him/her with a Release build. Use the debug version for your own development tests/purposes.